# Osgi with Java EE 6 Getting started

Tags: osgi, java-ee-6, jboss7.x

I am trying to develop a service where in all the different stacks e.g Persistence, Security, etc. run as OSGi bundles in an OSGi container. I am using JBoss AS 7.1.1 as my OSGi container.

I used the following JBoss stack to setup my project.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.bom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0-with-osgi</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

However, I was thinking the `Manifiest.MF` as well as activator classes will be auto-generated (not that i have a problem doing this), but to my surprise, nothing happens and I am bumped on that.

Also i cannot figure out how to wire services provided by different OSGi bundles together in a web application.

Most of the examples I see are targeting a Spring environment. Please, could someone point me in the Java EE 6 direction?

Comment: You say "JEE 6 Direction" but what is that markup? Is that Maven?

Comment: Yeah, thats maven. I mean almost all examples are spring oriented. I would like  to see one that is jee 6 based. the maven mark up is from jboss stacks.

Comment: Not a real answer, but have you looked at the books "Osgi in Action" and  "OSGi and Equinox"? They helped me when I was getting to grips with the whole web+osgi thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet for wiring is probably Blueprint. Blueprint can also replace Activators with eager singleton beans. Blueprint can't be used directly within the web bundle to register and consume services, but a JNDI-Blueprint bridge allows you to use JNDI lookups with an 'osgi:service' namespace.

You can find plenty of Blueprint and Enterprise OSGi tutorials if you google for Apache Aries, and you may find [Enterprise OSGi in Action](http://www.manning.com/cummins) useful. Chapters 1 and 2 are available free on the web.

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with JBoss AS, but you may find [OSGi Development with Eclipse IDE and JBoss AS 7](http://jaceklaskowski.pl/wiki/OSGi_Development_with_Eclipse_IDE_and_JBoss_AS_7) useful a bit. It uses OSGi DS, but in the listings I can see OSGi Blueprint is available, too. I think [Developing OSGi Applications with Blueprint bundles and WebSphere Application Server V8.5 Liberty Profile](http://jaceklaskowski.pl/wiki/Developing_OSGi_Applications_with_Blueprint_bundles_and_WebSphere_Application_Server_V8.5_Liberty_Profile) might be of some help.

Comment: Yes, I'm fairly confident JBoss supports Blueprint; almost all application servers which support the enterprise OSGi programming model do.

Comment: I recently stumbled on this project [link]http://mathieuancelin.github.com/weld-osgi/ that describes how to build an osgi weld service using the weld-osgi jars. I think its worth the time